# how could I do type casting in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to execute a method of instance of`A` on instance of `B`, where `A` and `B` are not related, independent classes.

```
a = A.new
b = B.new

b.<method_of_a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insane, senseless way:

```
class A
  def a_method
    'I am instance of A'
  end
end

class B
  def method_missing(method_name)
    if method_name.to_s =~ /a_method/
      A.instance_method(method_name).bind(self).call
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

B.new.a_method
#=> "I am instance of A"
```

---

Sane, idiomatic way:

```
module CommonMethods
  def common_method
    'I am available for all includers'
  end
end

class A
  include CommonMethods
end

class B
  include CommonMethods
end

a = A.new
b = B.new

a.common_method
#=> "I am available for all includers"
b.common_method
#=> "I am available for all includers"
```

Comment: this is working, may I request you to add one more example, how could I do `A.<class_method_of_b>`

Comment: @AmolPujari The code is there. Just look into it and add it where needs to go to make `A.<class_method_of_b>` work. If you really meant `class_method_of_b`, then 1) make sure to define a "class method". 2) define the `method_missing` as `self.method_missing` and you'll want to have `A.method(method_name).bind(self).call`

Comment: sorry my actual requirement is b.<class_method_of_A>, B is kind of collection class in my case

Comment: @AmolPujari the fact, that you've unchecked the answer does not mean I'll edit it. I discourage anyone else to add answers to this question. I will rollback the edit of your question, you will have to ask a new one. Changing the question and ***invalidating*** already given answers is not the way to go on SO.  The question *as it was in the beginning* **is** answered in this thread.

Comment: I agree, my bad!

Answer (score 3):

```
class A
  def yay!
    puts "¡YAY!"
  end
end
b = A.new
A.instance_method(:yay!).bind(b).()
#⇒ "¡YAY!"
```

Comment: You just unlocked something deep inside my head.

Comment: I still don't get the upvoting policy here. I've shown the exact same thing saying this is not something good to do, and you're still the the one "unlocking something deep inside" people's heads :D

Comment: @AndreyDeineko It’s because mine is longer (44 vs 32) :-P